# How use payable function with browser solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix

How use payable function using interface of browser solidity IDE Remix ?
http://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.11+commit.68ef5810.js

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `payable` function like in the following contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract testPay {
    function pay() payable {
    }
}
```

can be used just like a normal function call by clicking the button. Additionally, you can send Ether to the smart contract by filling out the `Value` field on the top, e.g. here I sent along 1 Ether
[image]

Once you click the button, not only your function will be called but also the contract will receive 1 Ether. Note that the default units are Ether not Wei.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question is then, how and where the received  Ether is stored?

Comment: It is stored at the contract address.

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2022:**

I recently tried to use a `payable` function in Remix and could not find the `Value` input described in previous [SCBuergel's answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/19549/98656). Remix changed its interface and move the `Gas Limit` and `Value` inputs.

As of today (Oct 2022), this inputs are located at the top of the left sidebar. At some point I was confused and thought they were only for the `deploy` section but then I realized that it is for the whole interaction. They moved all the transaction/wallet features to the top.

[image]

Comment: I can confirm, It works